# get kml coordinates on google map and adjust/drag coordinates on map using geoxml

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geoxml3

I have rendered/parsed KML file on google map. Now I need that whatever coordinates kml has that should be show on map and that I should able to drag those coordinates. Also I have drawing tools in my code. If that is draw then that should be also able to drag. I am not getting any resources for these functionalities.

My code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Complex</title>


  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=drawing&v=weekly"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/ProjectedOverlay.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var overlays = [];
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    
      var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.5814049819976, 73.9787511057671),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: "satellite",
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
          drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
          ],
        },
        markerOptions: {
          icon: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
        },
        // circleOptions: {
        //   fillColor: "#ffff00",
        //   fillOpacity: 1,
        //   strokeWeight: 5,
        //   clickable: false,
        //   editable: true,
        //   zIndex: 1,
        // },
        circleOptions: {
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#FF0000",
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
        },
        polygonOptions: {
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        },
        polylineOptions: {
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
        },
        rectangleOptions: {
          strokeColor: "#33DFFF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#33DFFF",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        },
      });
      drawingManager.setMap(map);
      google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
          overlays.push(event.overlay); // store reference to added overlay
      });

      var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        singleInfoWindow: true,
      //  afterParse: useTheData
       afterParse: function (doc) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++) {
                            var p = doc[0].placemarks[i];
                            console.log(doc[0].placemarks[i]);
                            clickablePolygon(p);
                        }
                    }      
        //   afterParse: function(doc) { // callback after parse
        //     for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++) {                
        //         console.log(doc[0].placemarks[i].LineString[0].coordinates) //for coordinates - doc[0].placemarks[i] get more info
        //     }
        // }
      });
      //geoXml.parse('./kml_files/KML_Samples.kml');
      geoXml.parse('./kml_files/golfpoly.kml');
      // alert("done init");
    }
    );
    function useTheData(doc) {
      // Geodata handling goes here, using JSON properties of the doc object
      for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].markers.length; i++) {
         console.log(doc[0].markers[i].title);
        jQuery('#map_text').append(doc[0].markers[i].title + ', ');
      }
    };

    
function clickablePolygon(p) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(
            p.polygon,
            "rightclick",
            function (event) {
                var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
                var latlng = {
                    lat: clickedLocation.lat(),
                    lng: clickedLocation.lng(),
                    zlevel: map.getZoom()
                };
            }
            );
        }

    // undo last overlay action
function removeLine() {
  var lastOverlay = overlays.pop();
  if (lastOverlay) lastOverlay.setMap(null);
};
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1">

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
    <button onclick="removeLine()">Undo Line</button>
    <div id="map_text"></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**MY KML file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>golfpoly.kml</name>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ffff5500</color>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>ff00aa55</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ffff5500</color>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>ff00aa55</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
        <name>golfpoly</name>
        <description>Golf club, Nashik</description>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        73.77706910664098,19.99557588191178,0 73.77680015227681,19.99516184216627,0 73.7769660838005,19.99455413693239,0 73.77741856668077,19.99433581882104,0 73.77795443692341,19.99445050861715,0 73.77823852664554,19.9948752467814,0 73.77807297962021,19.99545511968107,0 73.77752721622502,19.99569916551114,0 73.77706910664098,19.99557588191178,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Do you just want the polygons from KML to be editable?  (like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_geoxml3_20210609.html)) Please remove my google analytics tag from _your_ site (commenting out javascript tags doesn't always work as you expect).

Comment: @geocodezip yeah I am trying to achieve that but those points(co-ordinates of KML) should be editable. Also that drawing tools does not work if apply draggable code. I need KML coordinates and drawing tools dragable/editable. Its getting hard to find resources on those. Also I tried undo line as you can see in my code but that also not working. its reloading the page :-(

Comment: @geocodezip Also I know there are not just KML of polygons, there are KML of paths, placements etc. If possible i need to map and edit co-ordinates of all KML types. Please guide and help. Please suggest which tags I need to changes into which tags. I am new to this so trying out solutions which i found.

Comment: Do the same thing for each type of object from the KML you want editable/draggable.  The sample KML you provided in your question only has a single polygon.